# ヘルプページ「どこでもコメント」を全体的に改善したい

Tags: サポート, 翻訳, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンター > 権限 の「[どこでもコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)」において、日本語の表現が不自然な箇所があるため見直したいと思います。改善箇所等があれば直接編集をお願いします。

参考となる英語のページは [こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) です。

---

Title: どこでもコメント
Subtitle: 他のユーザーの投稿にコメントを残す

#### コメントとは？

コメントとは、質問または回答に残すことができる一時的な「付箋」のメモです。コメントにはプラス投票したり通報したりできますが、信用度は発生しません（なお、マイナス投票はできません）。編集履歴はなく、削除されると永遠になくなります。

自分の投稿にはいつでもコメントでき、自分の質問にまつわる投稿にもコメントできます。一方で、他のユーザーの投稿にコメントを残すには、[信用度を獲得](/help/whats-reputation)することで得られる権限が必要です。まだ獲得していない場合は、まずは回答を書くことに慣れてください。

#### コメントの方法は？

各投稿の [`コメントの追加`] リンクをクリックします。コメントは複数行にはできません。

コメントでは [Markdown の一部](/editing-help#comment-formatting) をサポートしており、`_斜体_` や `**太字**`、`[名前付きリンク](http://example.com)` などが可能です。

#### コメントするとどうなりますか？

コメントは、以下のコミュニティメンバーに自動的に通知されます。

- コメントした投稿の所有者
- コメントに @username reply が含まれる場合、もう 1 人のユーザー<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> @reply できるのは、すでにコメントを残したか投稿を編集したユーザーのみです。@username のスペース以外の最初の 3 文字は、最後に残されたコメントまたは編集から開始して名前のマッチングに使用されます。詳しくは[「コメントへの返答はどのように機能しますか？」](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/43019)をご覧ください。

#### どんな時にコメントしたらいいですか？

次のような場合はコメントを送信してください。

- 作成者に対して**明確化**をリクエストする
- 作成者が投稿を改善するのに役立つ**建設的な指摘**を残す
- 関係するが**些細な情報や一時的な情報**を投稿に追加する（関係する質問へのリンクを加えたり、質問が更新されたことを作成者に知らせたりなど）

#### コメントしては**いけない**のはどんな場合ですか？

以下の場合にはコメントは推奨されません。

- 投稿の意味を本質的には変更しない**修正の提案**。この場合は、[編集を行う](/help/editing) か [編集を提案](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) してください。
- **質問への回答**または既存の回答に対する別の解決法の提供。この場合は、実際の回答を投稿するか、既存のものを編集して拡張してください。
- 新しい情報を追加しない**賛辞**（「+1、優れた回答ですね！」）。この場合は、プラス投票して[感謝の気持ちを示しましょう](/help/how-to-answer)。
- 建設的なものを何も追加しない**指摘**（「-1、前のコメントを見ろよ！」）。この場合はマイナス投票するか、よりよい他の回答にプラス投票してください。
- **二次的に派生した議論**や賛否が分かれる点についての議論。この場合は[チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ja.stackoverflow.com)を使用してください。
- **コミュニティのふるまいや、サイトポリシーに関する議論**。この場合は[メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)を使用してください。

Comment: リンク先 URL に使われている `$ChatUrl` と `$MetaUrl` は有効ですか？ 現在のヘルプページには反映されていないようです。確認してみて下さい。

Comment: なお、当初は1行であった HTML に私が改行とインデントを追加しています。
無いとは思いますが、もしも1行のHTMLが必要になるようであれば、minify ツールで再度変形できます（連絡いただければ私がやります）。

Comment: ヘルプはページによってソースが HTML だったり Markdown だったりでマチマチですが、一定のルールはありますか？ (可能なら Markdown を使った方が個人的には書きやすいかなと感じます)

Comment: @cubick Markdown への書き換えはもちろん大丈夫です！supaさんが懸賞の時に書き換え[HTML -> Markdown](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3391/6) を行なってくださったような感じになるかと。

Comment: @mjy 大変見やすくなっています、ありがとうございます！改行くださったおかげで Markdown へ書き換えやすくなったかと。（1行のHTMLは特に必要なさそうです！）

Comment: 「投稿の意味を本質的には変更しない修正の提案」というのは用語の訂正など、明確な間違いの修正といったことですか？

Comment: 「新しい情報を追加しない賛辞」、これは回答に対する文面での評価を禁止するということでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

#### 意図された原文との違い

意図された原文と違う翻訳を列挙します。必要に応じて編集してください。

- 斜体（`<em>`）指定は、削除するか太字（`<strong>`）に
- Enter の押下による投稿機能は日本語版では無効

Answer (score 1):

スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版ではEnterでの投稿が無効であることが確認できたため、当ヘルプの内容をサイトに反映いたしました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: このメタ質問の最初のコメントで指摘した `$ChatUrl` と `$MetaUrl` の件ですが、やはり更新後もリンクになっていないようです。
担当のプログラマに確認が取れないならば、これからはこういった変数の使用は止めて、URL 直書きの方が良いかも知れませんね。

Comment: @mjy  `$ChatUrl` と `$MetaUrl`　についてのコメントをすっかり見落としておりました！再度お教えくださりどうもありがとうございます。URLを直接追加編集いたしまして、もう一度ヘルプの反映依頼をかける予定ですのでしばらくお待ちくださいませ。